# How do I make individual labels for multiple data points in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My data file is a .csv (data below) with one column called myletters. It has 3 rows with the value A, 6 rows with the value B, 11 rows with the value C, and about 18 rows with the value D.

I am experimenting/learning and trying to make individual circles for each letter value and place them in 4 different x,y coordinates based on the value (A,B,C, or D).  This works.  My problem is I want to create a label for A, B, C, or D but the .text is pulling in every instance of my value which causes the label to be progressively darker depending on how many instances of each letter.  A is black but D is very, very heavy black.

```
    const margin = {left: 170, top: 50, bottom: 50, right: 20}
    const width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right
    const height = 950 - margin.top - margin.bottom

    const coordinates = {
    'A': [300,150],
    'B': [450,150], 
    'C': [300,400],
    'D': [450,400] } ;    

    const svg = d3.select("#vis")
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 1000)
    .attr('height', 950)
    .attr('opacity', 1)
        
    const x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain([1, 2, 3,4])
    .range([150,300,450,550])

    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain([1, 2, 3,4])
    .range([ "#F8766D", "#00BA38", "#619CFF","#666666"])
 
      
    d3.csv('../data/testdata.csv').then(data => {
    const xAccessor = d => d.myletters

    const unique_value = [...new Set(data.map((item) => item.myletters))];

    const nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .style("fill", d=> color(xAccessor(d)))
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.8)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr('r', 7)
    .style("stroke-width", 1)

    simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    simulation  
    .force('forceX',d3.forceX(d=> coordinates[xAccessor(d)][0])) //works
    .force('forceY',d3.forceY(d=> coordinates[xAccessor(d)][1])) //workd     
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(width / 2).y(height / 2)) 
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(10)) 
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().strength(1).radius(8).iterations(5)) 
   
    .on("tick", function(d){
    nodes
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y)
          
    });

    //add label rectangle
     svg.selectAll('my_rect')
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append('rect')
    .attr('x',d=> coordinates[xAccessor(d)][0]) 
    .attr('y',d=> coordinates[xAccessor(d)][1]) 
    .attr('width',50)
    .attr('height', 30)
    .style("fill", d=> color(xAccessor(d)))
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.2)
    .attr("stroke", "#989898")
    const texts =  svg.selectAll('mytext')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
         
    texts
                 
    .attr('x',d=> coordinates[xAccessor(d)][0]) 
    .attr('y',d=> coordinates[xAccessor(d)][1]) 
    .attr('font-size','12px')
    .attr('text-anchor','middle')
    .text(d => xAccessor(d))   

         
              
                     

    })
    //csv data
    myletters
    A
    A
    A
    B
    B
    B
    B
    B
    B
    C
    C
    C
    C
    C
    C
    C
    C
    C
    C
    C
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
    D
```

I tried .data(unique_values) instead of .data(data) but that just lists A,B,C,D in each box.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you have right now, and if possible show what you desire?

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply.  I would like to have the letter "A" in the pink box, the letter "B" in the green box, etc.  However, I want to be able to do this using my data file because ultimately in my real project I might not pre-know what the label values will be or there may be a lot of clusters. - Thanks.

Comment: Please post `../data/testdata.csv` to make your code sample working

Comment: I suppose you need to put lables inside your 'boxes' (rectangles). Am I right?

Comment: Thank you for reviewing this.  I added the CSV data at the bottom. I also updated my screenshot.  The problem is the letter A is light black because there are three instances of A.  However D is very dark black/bold because there are almost 20 instances of D.  This would make sense if I wanted a letter label in each circle but I don't. I would like to have a label of just one instance of the letter in the rectangular box. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `unique_value`. Here is the modified code:

```js
svg
  .selectAll("my_rect")
  .data(unique_value) // use unique_value
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d) => coordinates[d][0]) // no longer use xAccessor
  .attr("y", (d) => coordinates[d][1]) // no longer use xAccessor
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 30)
  .style("fill", (d) => color(d)) // no longer use xAccessor
  .style("fill-opacity", 0.2)
  .attr("stroke", "#989898");

const texts = svg.selectAll("mytext")
  .data(unique_value) // use unique_value
  .enter()
  .append("text");

texts
  .attr("x", (d) => coordinates[d][0]) // no longer use xAccessor
  .attr("y", (d) => coordinates[d][1]) // no longer use xAccessor
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text((d) => d); // no longer use xAccessor
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is solved. I appreciate your time.